# How to convert java.io.InputStream to java.sql.Blob

Tags: java, jdbc

How do I convert a `java.io.InputStream` to a `java.sql.Blob` using pure Java?

In response to tbodt's suggestions, I ran the following through the eclipse debugger.  The debugger shows that `myinputstream` has content, but that `blob` remains `null` at the end of the code.  What do I need to do to fix this?

```
byte[] contents;
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int count;
while ((count = myinputstream.read(buffer)) != -1){output.write(buffer, 0, count);}//debugger says myinputstream has blksize 16384, buffcount 12742, and max 127394 here
contents = output.toByteArray();
Blob blob = null;
try {blob = new SerialBlob(contents);} 
catch (SerialException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

someObject.setSomeBlobProperty(blob);//debugger says blob is null here
```

I also ran the `IOUtils` approach through the debugger, but got the exact same results, with a `null` `blob` but a populated `myinputstream`.  How can I fix this?

```
Blob blob = null;
try {
    blob = new SerialBlob(IOUtils.toByteArray(myinputstream));//debugger says myinputstream has contents here.
    someObject.setSomeBlobProperty(blob);//debugger says blob is null here
} 
catch (SerialException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

In both cases, the debugger says `myinputstream` has `blksize` 16384, `buffcount` 12742, and `max` 127394 at the indicated locations, despite `blob` remaining `null`.  I also checked the underlying MySQL database after running this code and confirmed that the blob field is empty.

I then ran the following through the Eclipse debugger, which showed that the `byte[]` called `content` remained empty after the attempts to populate it.  So the resulting `blob` is empty, while the `inputstream` does indeed continue to have the same content values as shown above:

```
Blob blob = null;
byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(myinputstream);
try {
    blob = new SerialBlob(content);//debugger says content is empty here
    someObject.setSomeBlobProperty(blob);//debugger says blob is empty here.
}//debugger says myinputstream has the same values as in edit#1
catch (SerialException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Nice Pokémon exception handling there!

Comment: What's in `contents` in your first example?

Comment: And WTF is wrong with `SerialBlob` that it does a byte-by-byte copy instead of using `System.arraycopy`?

Comment: @chrylis the inputstream is an email attachment that contains an xml file. Javamail likes to treat attachments as inputstreams instead of files for some reason.

Comment: Not your input stream. Set a breakpoint and look at the actual byte array after you've attempted to read into it.

Comment: @chrylis I posted the results of your suggestions in **EDIT#2** at the end of my OP.  The debugger says that the `byte array` is empty after the attempt to populate it.

Comment: How are you getting the inputstream. Is it being accessed before the toByteArray call? Try calling a `reset` on the inputstream before calling toByteArray.

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra `InputStream.reset()` is only used in conjunction with `InputStream.mark()`, which may not be supported, and which the OP is not calling here.

Comment: If it was still null there must have been an exception. What was it?

Comment: Just get the `Blob`'s output stream and copy the input stream to it. Don't try to read the whole thing into memory. The whole point of a `Blob` is that it can be arbitrarily large.

Answer (score -1):

The easy way:

```
contents = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
```

But for that, you need Apache Commons IO, which might be hard to add. If you don't want to use it, or can't, here's one way of doing it yourself;

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int count;
while ((count = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
    output.write(buffer, 0, count);
contents = output.toByteArray();
```

Comment: I added the results to the end of my OP.  The blob is null.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm. In your debugger, try stepping into `IOUtils.toByteArray`, and see if what happens when it actually tries to read from the input stream. `toByteArray` actually calls `copy`, which calls a number of other methods until you get to the real copying code, so you'll have to step in pretty far.

Comment: There is no need for the `ByteArrayOutputStream` here. Complete waste of time and space. Just do this copy directly to the `Blob`'s output stream. That's what it's for.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the same:

```
Blob xmlForSign=null;
xmlForSign.getBinaryStream();
```

this method getBinaryStream() return an Inputfilestream.

Comment: This would throw a `NullPointerException`.